# Bluetooth doesn't work on Windows 7

Tags: bluetooth

I have a Asus-n73sv-v1g-tz462v laptop, Windows 7. I have Atheros Bluetooth installed but it doesn't connect to my Bluetooth Speaker (Philips SBT75/12), nor any other device.
I tried by installing the latest Atheros Bluetooth 7.4.0.130 driver, but still nothing.

After checking Services and Applications/ Services/Bluetooth Support Device/Properties it seems everything is active and working, only the Remote Prodecure Call (RPC) that is linked to the Bluetooth support Device, is not active nor is the RPC function (system restore) one can use if RPC isn't working.

Might that be the source of the problem?

Thanks Chris, I will give it a try.I haven't found the switch you mentioned. http://www.asus.com/Notebooks_Ultrabooks/N73SV/#specifications 
Kind regards, RemcoR

Ohhh THAT switch (LOL). It was ON. The wird thing is, now and again I get the message that Bluetooth cannot connect to the Bluetooth radio.

Answer (score 1):

I assume this laptop has a hardware switch for switch on/off radio (WLAN/Bluetooth). But also after switch ON this, BT doesn't work...
Additional you should activate BT/WLAN by using the "fn + F2" button (maybe another function key - look to the radio icon).
I am note sure, because I have another machine, but here there comes up a pop up, where I can active WLAN, BT, ... maybe it works in this way at your machine?! ;)

Comment: Thanks Chris, I will give it a try.I haven't found the switch you mentioned. http://www.asus.com/Notebooks_Ultrabooks/N73SV/#specifications

Comment: Saw the switch on this picture (next to the SD card slot): http://www.google.de/imgres?hl=de&biw=1603&bih=971&tbm=isch&tbnid=08sBOca3o3C2NM:&imgrefurl=http://nl.hardware.info/reviews/2278/5/apple-17-inch-macbook-pro-vs-asus-n73sv-opgeruimde-visie&docid=IYTRFjho5vwvBM&imgurl=http://content.hwigroup.net/images/products/xl/123703-4.jpg&w=1630&h=1080&ei=fy0qUdmWCdHSsgb2ioDABg&zoom=1&iact=hc&vpx=764&vpy=133&dur=3245&hovh=183&hovw=276&tx=131&ty=106&sig=102804509118506020272&page=1&tbnh=140&tbnw=202&start=0&ndsp=46&ved=1t:429,i:91